# qgis 2.8 openlayers plugin : google & OSM

Tags: openstreetmap, google-earth, qgis-openlayers-plugin, qgis-2.8

I'm working currently for a big project with QGIS 2.8 (windows). I would like load satellite images (google or OSM for instance) as baselayer. I know the usefull plugin called openlayers plugin. I would like ask 2 questions please.

1/ Am i allowed to load and to generate maps with google earth images satellite (via qgis/openlayersplugin) in a professional context ?

2/ If it not the case,i could  maybe use openstreet map satellite base layer (free licence). But it seems to be impossible to load OSM satellite image via your plugin openlayers layer?

Is there a way to load Openstreetmap satellite image baselayer into Qgis?

Answer (score 1):

You are allowed to do with Google Earth images whatever you want, if you pay them the license fee they want. (I know this is not the answer you want to read, but you better not mess with their license terms).

Openstreetmap does not have any satellite images, only road and landuse vector data. It is allowed to use bing imagery for digitizing within OSM, but bing might use license terms similar to Google for other use cases.

Comment: In addition see the [OSM license FAQ](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Legal_FAQ) if you create content out of the maps or datasets.